# Batch script to copy a file from one network share to another based on lastmodified or creation date

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have two network shared drives: lets call them: **DriveA** and **DriveB**.

There are two files which get generated at **DriveA** on a daily basis, and I want to copy the latest files to **DriveB/Folder1/fileA** and **DriveB/Folder2/fileB** everyday.

Can anyone please provide me solution wherein I can copy the files based on creation date:

1. Copy fileA(*creation date: 17July*) to **DriveB/Folder1**
2. Copy fileB(*creation date: 17July*) to **DriveB/Folder2**

I did come up with a solution but, it copies the file based on "today's date".

`SET usernameID=useremail@domain.com
SET usernameDOMAIN=11111111
SET password=pwd@1234
net use "\\111.444.222.777\FOLDER" /USER:%usernameID% %password% /persistent:no
set source=\\222.111.333.444\FOLDER\FOLDER2\Report_
net use "\\DOMAIN\storage\2012-0151_hms_ux\Hadoop\LiveDataLandingZoneDWH" /user:usermail@domain.com pwd@1234 /persistent:no
set dest=\\code1\storage\2012-0151_hms_ux\Hadoop\LiveDataLandingZoneDWH\Input\Report\Report_
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x
set today=%MyDate:~0,4%%MyDate:~4,2%%MyDate:~6,2%
echo %today%
:copy
copy "%source%%today%0700.csv" "%dest%%today%0700.csv"
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto disconnect
goto end
pause
:disconnect 
goto end
pause
:end
pause`

EDIT 1:

Now I'm using the below command to copy the files on the date 16/Jul/2017:
`xcopy C:\Users\Desktop\report\ActualHRC_*.csv C:\Users\Downloads /D:07-16-2017
pause`

How can I provide the `/D:m-d-y` dynamically? I mean, the variables should take the `m`, `d` and `y` from the system.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have made things way too complicated. There is a very simple solution: `xcopy /Y/D`.

If you just type `xcopy /?` you can see all the options.  For the `/D` option, it says:

> Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
>   If no date is given, copies only those files whose
>   source time is newer than the destination time.

There is also `robocopy`, which is also built into windows, offers even more options, and is allegedly capable of copying from network share to network share using UNC pathnames. (so, no drive mapping necessary.)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I will try it put right now

Comment: my source contains files named like: fileA_201707170070.txt, fileB_201707170070.txt.
But here it gets more complex, the timestamp in the file-name changes sometime, it gets incremented by an hour or two. How to face this complexity?

Comment: It is best to arrange things so that you do not have to deal with this complexity.  Files already have creation/modification date attributes, so duplicating this information in the filename is only useful for avoiding filename collisions; it should not be relied upon for anything else.  The `/D` parameter of xcopy will copy any files that either do not exist in the destination, or, if they exist, then it will copy them only if they are of a newer date.  If you are removing old files from the destination, then you need to save the date of last removal and use it in `/D:m-d-y`.

Comment: Hello @Mike Nakis, can you please review my EDIT 1 ?

Comment: Do you have to provide m-d-y dynamically?  If you omit them, then the copy will take place if the source file is newer than the destination, or if the destination does not exist.